# Multiple independent sections in one textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a kind of form that has one big `textarea` but divided on smallers ones, to put it simple I would like to create something like this:

```
Section 1
Text text text
--------------
Section 2
text text text
--------------
Section 3
text text text
--------------
```

etc.

And make it all in one `textarea` BUT when I click in section 1 area file_1 would load (and I ofc could edit the text in that particular section) and when I click section 2 the file_2 would load (names are just examples).
If it's impossible or really complicated to make what would be best approach to this problem? Keep in mind that there would be at least 20--30 sections and they should be created dynamically.

I was thinking if it is possible to make it in HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but I do not really see the point. The way to do it is to always use white space separators and not allow the user to add such separators or remove them. Then, you can get the different sections by `split`-ing the value of your `textarea` by the separator and initialize them by loading the file into an array and `join`-ing it.

But why would you want to overcomplicate your own life this way and to force yourself to implement slow and hacky algorithms? You could use several `textarea` tags and design them in such a way that they will look like they are a single `textarea`. The only thing to handle besides that would be to switch the `textarea` when the user presses down/up arrow for instance in the last/first row of a `textarea`.

Comment: To be honest I was thinking of some nicer solution, since making 30-40 textareas that look like one seems pretty rough. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Krolik if you plan your design well, then the number of textareas will not really matter from this point of view. You can do it with a div containing multiple p tags and design them to look the way you want if that's a better fit for you in terms of design, but then all the functionality which you get for free from a textarea will have to be implemented.